# Is a 1-hour connection enough at Kyiv Boryspil with two separate tickets?

Tags: short-connections, ukraine, connecting-flights, kbp

I'm looking into buying two separate tickets to fly from Vienna to Minsk, with a connection at Kyiv Boryspil airport. Ukrainian Airlines comes out best, but there would be only 1 hour between flights.

Is it possible to connect in 1 hour (I would have only carry-on baggage)? What if I miss the connecting flight due to delays?

Ukrainian Airlines also sells the same ticket with the same 1-hour layover, but the price of the single ticket is very high compared to two separate tickets.

Answer (score 1):

At KBP you'll have enough time to run to another gate within the terminal D, but remember that 1 hour leaves you no margin for a possible delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you miss the second flight, you'll have to buy another ticket - the risk will fall upon you.  So no, I would never do this.

The one time I did something similar, I booked a four-hour layover between flights.  There's still risk with that, but it's much safer.